# reportlab: flowables in flowable

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to have a flowable which is just a box who has a fixed width and height but can take several flowables as its content. So the flowables in this box should think the end of the box is the end of the page (e. g. a paragaph should break the line if the width of the box is not enough).

My first attempt looks like this:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Flowable

class Box(Flowable):

    def __init__(self, width, height, flowables=[]):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.flowables = flowables

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        for flowable in self.flowables:
           # how to handle flowables that they 
           # match into this flowable?
```

After some research I found that I have to implement two methods: `wrapOn()` and `drawOn()`. But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You seem to be trying to solve the problem that frames already solve.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't notice that Frames are the thing I'm searching for. I'm just trying to figure this out at the moment.